# Entity Framework Delete Many to Many Relationship using stubs

Tags: c#

I am trying to delete a many-many relationship entry between two entities without querying either of them first. Something along the lines of:

```
Foo foo = new Foo() {Id = 1};
context.Foos.Attach(foo);
context.Entry(foo).State = EntityState.Modified;

Bar bar = new Bar { Id = 2 };
context.Bars.Attach(bar);
context.Entry(bar).State = EntityState.Modified;

// This doesn't work: no exceptions but the relationship doesn't get deleted
foo.Bars = new List<Bar> { bar };
foo.Bars.Remove(bar);

context.SaveChanges();
```

How can I remove bar from foo.Bars relationship without first querying either entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the stub entities be `Unchanged` and in a relationship that is also in `Unchanged` state (call `AcceptAllChanges` after `foo.Bars = new List<Bar> { bar };`). Only then `foo.Bars.Remove(bar);` will put the relationship in `Deleted` state and `SaveChanges` will delete it. You can verify what's happening by inspecting the underlying `ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager` - it has dictionaries for entities and relationships by their states. If you're not using proxies you may need to `DetectChanges`.

Comment: Solved. Your answer was pretty much the way to do it. I did it a little differently, by first creating the POCOS, and running the Attach command after the List was created, but the end result is the same. On Attach, the state is marked as unchanged and the operation succeeds. Thank you.